# Group by in rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I'm trying to create a group query on a MongoDB collection similar to:

```
db.orders.group( {
    key: { ord_dt: 1, 'item.sku': 1 },
    cond: { ord_dt: { $gt: new Date( '01/01/2012' ) } },
    reduce: function ( curr, result ) { },
    initial: { }
} )
```

I'm using rmongodb. From going over the rmongodb package documentation, they use `mongo.command` to run a count command:

```
mongo <- mongo.create() 
if (mongo.is.connected(mongo)) {
    buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create() 
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "count", "people") 
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "query", mongo.bson.empty()) 
    command <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf) 
    result = mongo.command(mongo, "test", command) 
    if (!is.null(result)) {  
        iter = mongo.bson.find(result, "n") print(mongo.bson.iterator.value(iter)) 
    }
}
```

also distinct:

```
mongo.distinct <- function(mongo, db, collection, key) {    
    b <- mongo.command(mongo, db, list(distinct=collection, key=key))    
    if(!is.null(b))
        b <- mongo.bson.value(b, "values")
    }
names <- mongo.distinct(mongo, "test", "people", "name")
```

Has anyone had success in using `mongo.command` to do a group query?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example for a simple "GROUP BY statement" using the aggregation framework. Note that this requires MongoDB version 2.1 or later: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/

First make the connection and some dummy data:

```
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create()

db <- "stackoverflow"
coll <- "grpmong"
ns <- paste(db, coll, sep = ".")

mongo.insert(mongo, ns, mongo.bson.from.list(list(y=1, x=1)))
mongo.insert(mongo, ns, mongo.bson.from.list(list(y=1, x=2)))
mongo.insert(mongo, ns, mongo.bson.from.list(list(y=2, x=3)))
mongo.insert(mongo, ns, mongo.bson.from.list(list(y=2, x=4)))
```

Check the format of the data:

```
 >mongo.find.one(mongo, ns, mongo.bson.empty())
    _id : 7          51e002b881620de5fe2973ec
    y : 1    1.000000
    x : 1    1.000000
```

The following will produce the equivalent of:

```
SELECT y '_id', SUM(x) total
FROM grpmong
GROUP BY y
```

Create the "GROUP BY statement"

```
x <- list('$group' = list('_id' = '$y',
                          'total' = list('$sum' = '$x')
                          ))
grpBSON <- mongo.bson.from.list(x)
```

Create the aggregation pipeline and add the "GROUP BY statement" into it:

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create();
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "aggregate", coll); 
  mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "pipeline");
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "0", grpBSON);
  mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf);
cmd <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf);
```

Run the command:

```
res <- mongo.command(mongo, db, cmd)
```

Inspect the result:

```
> print(res)
result : 4
  0 : 3
    _id : 1 2.000000
    total : 1 7.000000
  1 : 3
    _id : 1 1.000000
    total : 1 3.000000
  ok : 1 1.000000
```